# zendX Jquery - Plugin by name was not found in the registry

Tags: zend-framework, zendx

I've followed this tutorial on zendcast for creating an autocomplete with ajax:

http://www.zendcasts.com/autocomplete-control-with-zendx_jquery/2010/07/

I get "Plugin by name 'AutocompleteElement' was not found in the registry"

which must be to do with this code I have in IndexAction

`

$this->view->autocompleteElement = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Autocomplete('ac');

$this->view->autocompleteElement->setLabel('Autocomplete');

$this->view->autocompleteElement->setJqueryParam('source','index/results');

`

Does anybody know where I should be looking to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

solved it, I wasn't calling it correctly in index.phtml :/